# systemd service fails on boot but success on shell

Tags: mount, systemd, fuse

OS : ubuntu server 18.04 LTS

PLEXDRIVE 5.0

I'm using plexdrive and made service script like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Plexdrive
AssertPathIsDirectory=/srv/plex
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=siegfried2p
ExecStart=/usr/bin/plexdrive mount -c /home/siegfried2p/.plexdrive -o allow_others /srv/plex
ExecStop=/bin/fusermount -uz /srv/plex
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and systemctl status says Assertion failed

then when I lookup mount folder shell says

> cannot access 'plex': Transport endpoint is not connected

I can fix it with

> sudo fusermount -u /srv/plex

and when unmounted I can start service manually and it successd
but every time i reboot same thing happens
I also checked /etc/mtab and found this

> /dev/fuse /srv/plex fuse
>    rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1004,allow_other 0 0

I suspect that just before or after reboot, fusermount fails and that cause Transport endpoint disconnection
but I don't familiar with fuse so I can't find problem

Answer (score 0):

put ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10 solved problem

I don't know why exactly maybe order of service execution problem